# Can't create a new session from `run-shell` in tmux

Tags: bash, tmux

I have this +x script

`~/bin/tmux-test.sh`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

tmux neww
```

and in my `.tmux.conf`:

```
bind -n M-g run-shell `~/bin/tmux-test.sh`
```

It works...
...but if I change `tmux neww` to `tmux new` (for creating a new session) then when I press the keybind tmux shows this error on screen :

```
'/home/me/bin/tmux-test.sh' returned 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, tmux does not support `` `..` `` style quoting.

And by default `tmux new` (not `:new`) would refuse to create new session if you are already in tmux:

```
$ echo $TMUX
/private/tmp/tmux-502/default,2554,0
$ tmux new
sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force
```

You can use `tmux new -d` to create a *detached* session and then switch to it.

##### ~/bin/tmux-test.sh

```
tmux new -d -s foo
tmux switch-client -t foo
true
```

##### tmux.conf

```
bind -n M-g run-shell ~/bin/tmux-test.sh
```

Comment: Thanks, for me it doesn't make sense why `new -A -s foo` won't work and why I have to use `switch-client` to switch the "session" when running this shell command from within tmux already but if I write the same command `new -A -s foo` in `^:` it works, tmux is not that intuitive sometimes. I don't understand why people wants to close my question... Anyways thanks!

Comment: when u use `:new ...` the command is executed by your current attached tmux process but for `tmux new` it's executed by a new tmux process. i think tmux behaves differently in such 2 scenarios.

Comment: "tmux is not that intuitive sometimes" -- that's very true based on my experience.

Comment: Ok I understand the difference now. Anyways I've been able to use tmux popup and fzf and thanks to your help I can now open the selected git repository in another session! You made my day